# Are exact logistic regression and conditional logistic regression the same?

Tags: logistic, conditional, exact-test

I have seen these two terms in practice. Are they actually referring to the same method? If not, what is the main difference between the two methods?

Conditional logistic regression is commonly used in case control studies, where matched case and control subjects are compared using this model adjusted for matching covariates.
For example,
https://www.thelancet.com/journals/eclinm/article/PIIS2589-5370(20)30318-7/fulltext

I have seen exact logistic regression being proposed in some clinical trial protocols for some binary outcome with small sample size. But for conditional logistic regression used in case control studies, I am not sure if it is for small sample size. Therefore, I am not sure if the two methods are referring to the same thing.

Comment: Please provide context: where did you hear those terms? Could you provide citation?

Comment: Yes the terms are interchangeable

Comment: I have edited the question with some context.

Comment: Exact logistic regression uses the conditional likelihood, but regression using the conditional likelihood is not necessarily (not even usually) exact -- it usually uses asymptotic approximations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, context.

There are two statistical problems being solved. First, the maximum likelihood estimators for logistic regression are inconsistent if the number of parameters grows too fast with the sample size. At the extreme, with binary matched pair data $Y_{ij}$ $j=0,1$ and the model
$$\textrm{logit}\, P(Y_{ij}=1|X_{ij}=x)=\alpha_i+\beta x$$
the MLE of $\beta$ converges to $2\beta$.

The solution to this problem is a conditional likelihood: condition on $ Y_{i.}=\sum_j Y_{ij}$.  The maximum conditional likelihood estimator of $\beta$ is consistent and has all the usual nice properties.  The conditional likelihood has the same form as the Cox partial likelihood in survival, and a popular way to implement conditional logistic regression involves calling Cox regression routines under the hood.

The usual inference in conditional logistic regression uses the asymptotic $\chi^2$ distribution of the log likelihood ratio or the asymptotic Normal distribution of $\hat\beta$. It can be a bit approximate in small samples (though the likelihood-based tests and intervals are pretty good). However, when the $x$s are discrete, one can write down the exact distribution of $Y_{ij}||X, Y_{i.}$.  It's possible to do exact tests (like more complicated versions of Fisher's exact test). With more effort, it's possible to do point and interval estimation with the exact conditional likelihood.

In most of statistics, it's not all that common that you have small samples, large enough effect sizes to see associations anyway, and a pressing need to know precisely whether your $p$-value is just above or just below 0.05. But some people do want this sort of thing; in particular, there is genuine demand for it in pharmaceutical clinical trials.

Cytel Software make a program, [LogXact](https://www.cytel.com/software/logxact/), that does exact conditional inference for logistic regression, as well as some Monte Carlo methods and some 'almost-exact' methods involving saddlepoint approximations.  Some saddlepoint methods were also published and implemented by [Bellio and Brazzale](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1391044), first for S-PLUS and then for R; Brazzale and Reid and Davison have a [very nice book](https://homes.stat.unipd.it/alessandrarosalbabrazzale/content/applied-asymptotics) on the topic.

Comment: It's worthwhile to keep in mind that "exact" doesn't mean what people think.  Many "exact" methods are not very accurate, e.g., Fisher's "exact" test, which is conservative.  This happens when an unconditional hypothesis morphs into a conditional one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I finally have some understanding of the difference. I have only seen exact logistic regression and exact Poisson regression in the context of clinical trials, sometimes for subgroup analysis. Regarding the conditional approach, it sometimes puzzles me that for continuous outcomes in cohort studies, they usually adjust for matching strata without the concern about growing number of parameters.

Comment: In linear models for continuous outcomes you *don't* get this bias -- there's bias in the residual variance estimates if you fit too many parameters, but the 'degrees of freedom correction' fixes it.